# Cross Multiplication

Tags: algebra-precalculus

When you are cross multiplying, for example, $\frac{4x}{4x+8} = \frac{9x}{10x-2}$, you multiply right? But in one of the math problems I got, (which is just like the previous example) : $\frac{4x+5}{21} = \frac{7x+5}{4x+17}$, requires adding to get the answer... how will I know when to add or multiply?

Comment: I hope this is what you meant in your question, the division is likely to be ambiguous.

Comment: Welcome to math stack echange! Why do you think you cannot crossmultiply in the second example ? You will get the quadratic equation $16x^2-59x-20=0$ by cross-multiplying. The solutions are $4$ and $-\frac{5}{16}$

Comment: There are often many ways to solve the same problem in mathematics.  Don't assume that the way the book/ teacher/ tutor/ etc solves it is the *only* way.  A good exercise might be to try to cross multiply to solve the second equation and add to solve the first.  See if you can get the same answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can solve both equations by either cross-multiplying or subtracting (if I understood what you mean correctly). They're essentially the same methods.

I'll solve the first equation in both methods.

$$\frac{4x}{4x+8}-\frac{9x}{10x-2}=\frac{4x(10x-2)-9x(4x+8)}{(4x+8)(10x-2)}$$

$$=\frac{4x(x-20)}{(4x+8)(10x-2)}=0\iff \begin{cases}4x(x-20)=0\\(4x+8)(10x-2)\neq 0\end{cases}\iff x\in\{0,20\}$$

When solving by cross-multiplying, note that $4x+8\neq 0$ and $10x-2\neq 0$, which you must assume before cross-multiplying. Your equation is equivalent to:

$$\begin{cases}4x(10x-2)=9x(4x+8)\\4x+8\neq 0\\ 10x-2\neq 0\end{cases}\iff \begin{cases}4x(x-20)=0\\4x+8\neq 0\\10x-2\neq 0\end{cases}\iff x\in\{0,20\}$$

Answer (score 0):

After cross-multiplying,it is not done yet .Only after the terms are brought to one side of equation you can solve the quadratic equation,it is implied at times.